# Robolectric, AsyncTasks and Threads

Tags: java, android, testing, android-asynctask, robolectric

I've recently started using Robolectric for unit testing some of my android applications and have stumbled across a problem. In a few places I use AsyncTasks to do some background computations, and then update the UI depending on the outcome of these calculations. If I use `execute()` to exectue the AsyncTask, when I run my tests to check if the UI has been correctly update it passes. However, for various reasons, I am actually using `exectueOnExecutor()` with the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` parameter. When I run the tests with this the tests fail with it thinking that the UI has not been updated. Similarly if I do this from a thread and post back to the UI thread I have the same issue. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can always view how they use Robolectric to test AsyncTasks. https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAsyncTaskTest.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of searching [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290867/asynctask-test-doesnt-execute) thread helped me to resolve my issue.
In simple steps, you must create a new class that will shadow your AsyncTasks that are using `executeOnExecutor()` due to what appears to be a bug in the Robolectric framework. Here is the example from the aforementioned thread:

```
@Implements(AsyncTask.class)
public class MyShadowAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends ShadowAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

  @RealObject private AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> realAsyncTask;

    @Implementation
    public AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeOnExecutor(Executor executor, Params... params) {
        return super.execute(params);
    }       
}
```

Other than possibly changing the name of the class I did not need to change anything else to get it to work. The last step is simply to annotate your test class with

`@Config(shadows={MyShadowAsyncTask.class})`

Works wonderfully for me.

Comment: Have you tried [`flushBackgroundThreadScheduler()`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/Robolectric.html) ?